# Flutter: unexpected behavior using package ConvexBottomBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-packages, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using [ConvexBottomBar](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar) as my package for the bottom navigation bar. I have 2 problems, and the solutions for them are incompatible:

1. There is no `selectedIndex`, so when I change the page manually (sliding left or right), the tab bar would not update.

[image]

To solve this, I added an `onChanged()` method that updates the tab bar when each view gets visible:

```
void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    _appBarKey.currentState!.tap(index);
  }
```

2. It is not possible to move directly from index 0 to 2, or vice-versa. As the page tab updates when the view in the center gets shown, it sets the tab to be in index 1.

[image]

The solution for this would be removing the `onChanged()` method, but then the tab would not update.

It seems to me that the solutions for both bugs are incompatible. But there should be something I am able to do. This is my whole widget state:

```
class GameShellViewState extends State<GameShellView> {
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 1);

  void _onPageChanged(int index) {
    _appBarKey.currentState!.tap(index);
  }

  void _onTap(int index) {
    _pageController.animateToPage(index,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: PageView(
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: _onPageChanged,
        children: const [
          CareerView(),
          EducationView(),
          VidaView(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
        key: _appBarKey,
        elevation: 0,
        style: TabStyle.reactCircle,
        items: const [
          TabItem(icon: Icons.work, title: 'Career'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.school, title: 'Education'),
          TabItem(icon: Icons.heart_broken, title: 'Vida'),
        ],
        initialActiveIndex: 2,
        onTap: _onTap,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceVariant,
        activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the _onPageChanged() and _onTap() methods require an int index, so we can replace the 2 methods with one:

```
_changePage(int index){
  _appBarKey.currentState!.tap(index);
  _pageController.animateToPage(index,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
}
```

And then use this method in PageView

```
Scaffold(
  extendBody: true,
  body: PageView(
    controller: _pageController,
    onPageChanged: _changePage,
    ...
  ),
```

and ConvexAppBar:

```
bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
    ...
    onTap: _changePage,
    ...
  ),
```